# How to remove the superfluous "Launcher" GUI for Java CLI application

Tags: java, macos, user-interface

I am developing a command-line application (i.e. no GUI whatsoever) using `Java 8` and `mvn` running on `OS X` (and I currently have no idea if this problem manifests itself on other OSes). Development itself is going fine.

However when I start the application I get an unsightly GUI simply called "Launcher" (this is both the Application and the process name, see [image: the screenshot]). Even more annoying and egregious is that the first time the application does something more than just boot up, that "Launcher" steals focus from the GUI the user is working in at that moment. This is Highly Undesirable(tm).

Ideally what I want is to toss out the "launcher" GUI altogether, but failing that I could live with it no longer stealing the focus from the current GUI. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What does the about menu show?

Comment: There is no about menu. What you see in the screenshot encompasses the whole "GUI". However, clicking the "About Launcher" entry results in a generic pop-up with no title and the text: 
"About Launcher
  version 1.0 (1.0)."

Comment: That did it, thanks! I never ever would have guessed that solution.

Comment: @jjpe Glad to hear! I deleted my comment and rewrote it as an answer since it was only a guess, and would appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: I was actually just about to suggest that, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it as headless will cause the OS to treat your application a little differently. You should use headless mode when your application doesn't require any input beyond launch arguments, most commonly for daemon programs.

Here's some more information on headless mode:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

To set headless mode in code, use `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` as early as possible in your program; preferably in a static initializer in your main class.

You can also set it via JVM argument `-Djava.awt.headless`.

This also hides the Java icon in the dock on Mac OS X.

Comment: I use ZeroMQ sockets for I/O, but indeed there is no direct user interaction (I do use stdout for logging). Seems to be working fine in headless mode so far.

Also, I didn't know about the -D switch for headless mode so thanks for that, but in this case hardcoding it in is more appropriate.